# How to install grpcio on MacOS 13 with M1?

Tags: python, c++, macos, grpcio

I am trying to install **grpcio v1.47.0** using **pip** and **Python v3.8.13** on **MacOS v13.0** with **M1 Pro** but it fails with errors as below:

```
clang -w -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O3 -Wall -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include -I /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include -D_WIN32_WINNT=1536 -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_NAME_SUFFIX=\"Python\" -DGRPC_XDS_USER_AGENT_VERSION_SUFFIX=\"1.47.0\" -DOPENSSL_NO_ASM=1 -DGPR_BACKWARDS_COMPATIBILITY_MODE=1 -DHAVE_CONFIG_H=1 -DGRPC_ENABLE_FORK_SUPPORT=1 "-DPyMODINIT_FUNC=extern \"C\" __attribute__((visibility (\"default\"))) PyObject*" -DGRPC_POSIX_FORK_ALLOW_PTHREAD_ATFORK=1 -Isrc/python/grpcio -Iinclude -I. -Ithird_party/abseil-cpp -Ithird_party/address_sorting/include -Ithird_party/cares/cares/include -Ithird_party/cares -Ithird_party/cares/cares -Ithird_party/cares/config_darwin -Ithird_party/re2 -I/usr/include/openssl -Ithird_party/upb -Isrc/core/ext/upb-generated -Isrc/core/ext/upbdefs-generated -Ithird_party/xxhash -I/usr/include -I/Users/denis/Library/Caches/pypoetry/virtualenvs/auth-PxTXoSf9-py3.8/include -I/Users/denis/.pyenv/versions/3.8.13/include/python3.8 -c src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/listener/v3/quic_config.upb.c -o python_build/temp.macosx-13.0-arm64-cpython-38/src/core/ext/upb-generated/envoy/config/listener/v3/quic_config.upb.o -stdlib=libc++ -fvisibility=hidden -fno-wrapv -fno-exceptions -DHAVE_UNISTD_H -pthread
  In file included from src/core/ext/filters/census/grpc_context.cc:25:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/surface/call.h:33:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.h:65:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/iomgr/call_combiner.h:30:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/gprpp/mpscq.h:28:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/gprpp/sync.h:25:
  In file included from third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/synchronization/mutex.h:72:
  In file included from third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/synchronization/internal/kernel_timeout.h:34:
  In file included from third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/time/clock.h:26:
  third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/time/time.h:460:14: error: expected unqualified-id
      if (std::isnan(n))
               ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/math.h:165:5: note: expanded from macro 'isnan'
      ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_isnanf((float)(x))          \
      ^
  In file included from src/core/ext/filters/census/grpc_context.cc:25:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/surface/call.h:33:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/channel/channel_stack.h:65:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/iomgr/call_combiner.h:30:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/gprpp/mpscq.h:28:
  In file included from ./src/core/lib/gprpp/sync.h:25:
  In file included from third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/synchronization/mutex.h:72:
  In file included from third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/synchronization/internal/kernel_timeout.h:34:
  In file included from third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/time/clock.h:26:
  third_party/abseil-cpp/absl/time/time.h:461:19: error: expected unqualified-id
        return std::signbit(n) ? -InfiniteDuration() : InfiniteDuration();
                    ^
  /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/include/math.h:170:5: note: expanded from macro 'signbit'
      ( sizeof(x) == sizeof(float)  ? __inline_signbitf((float)(x))        \
      ^
```

I call **pip** as: `CFLAGS="-I /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/include" LDFLAGS="-L /opt/homebrew/opt/openssl/lib" GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYST EM_OPENSSL=1 GRPC_PYTHON_BUILD_SYSTEM_ZLIB=1 CC="clang -w" pip install grpcio==1.47.0`

I've tried a lot of variants already, even to pass paths to **absl** that was installed by **brew** and read all similar topics that I could find but it didn't help me.

How can I install it?

Comment: I had this exact same issue and the problem was my clang version (Apple clang version 13.1.6). Installing llvm from brew and then using that instead of apple clang worked for me.

Comment: @orhanhenrik can you please share how it can be done? Simply `brew install llvm` and then what?

Answer (score 1):

Works with grpcio-1.49.1 on macOS 12.6 using Xcode 14.0.1 and python 3.10.7 installed via brew.

```
% pip3.10 install grpcio
Collecting grpcio
  Using cached grpcio-1.49.1.tar.gz (22.1 MB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5.2 in /opt/homebrew/lib/python3.10/site-packages (from grpcio) (1.16.0)
Building wheels for collected packages: grpcio
  Building wheel for grpcio (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for grpcio: filename=grpcio-1.49.1-cp310-cp310-macosx_12_0_arm64.whl size=3905282 sha256=9c7b992a8ced88d08a85c796444047c2241513804a0acb1ebb0fef95d0aac24d
  Stored in directory: /Users/risner/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/6a/27/27/9ff38950d1bdf9deb4e7320c369478c85191c6ef22f92f18ec
Successfully built grpcio
Installing collected packages: grpcio
Successfully installed grpcio-1.49.1
```